# Torque wrench units

Tags: units

My torque wrench has these markings on it:

(da.  Nm.)  and on the line below  M.  KGS.

I can tell from comparing the scale to poundf-foot on the other side that the scale units are kilograms-meter but am struggling to understand those four markings.  Can anyone decipher?

Comment: Presumably Nm is Newton metres...

Answer (score 1):

Very cryptic way to write units, but it can be decrypted:

da.Nm= decaNewton.meter (http://www.deprag.se/omvandlare.pdf)

M.KGS=meter kilograms (http://www.thetoolhut.com/Torque-Conversion-English-Metric-Ft-lbs-M-kgs.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks!  It seems wrong to equate a force unit to a mass unit, but I see on a chart that there is such a thing as a "kilogram-forces" which is almost, but not quite equal to a decaNewton.

Comment: I agree, I believe is kilogram force, practically a decaNewton